# CreateDateTime in XPages SSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have written ServerSide JavaScript in Xpages as following below,
date format is "mm/dd/yyyy"

```
var date1:NotesDateTime=session.createDateTime("10/15/2013")
var date2:NotesDateTime=session.createDateTime("01/02/2014")
if(date1 <= date2)
{
return "Pass"
}
else
{
return "Fail"
}
```

Here I should get "Pass", but I am getting "Fail" ??????

Comment: In JavaScript putting the { on a new line adds burdon to the interpreter since it needs to evaluate if an auto insert of a ; is needed. Don't do this

Comment: And add your ; properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `timeDifference` method of `NotesDateTime` to compare date instances, not standard operators like `<` or `>`:

```
if (date1.timeDifference(date2) < 0) {
  return "Pass";
} else {
  return "Fail";
}
```

**NOTE:** the above can also be expressed more succinctly using the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
return (date1.timeDifference(date2) < 0) ? "Pass" : "Fail";
```

The `timeDifference` method essentially "subtracts" the date passed to it from the date instance upon which the method is called, returning the difference in seconds.

So, in the above example, if `date2` is later than `date1`, the method will return a negative number; if `date1` is later than `date2`, the result will be a positive number; the result will be `0` if both objects represent precisely the same date and time.

**BONUS INFO:**

The reason standard comparison operators cannot be used to identify a quantitative difference between the values of these two variables is because the variables are pointers to "objects", not "primitive" values.

JavaScript is an almost entirely typeless language, so the equality operator (`==`) is generally only reliable when used to compare strings, numbers, and booleans, and the comparison operators (`<`, `>`, etc.) are generally only reliable when used to compare numbers. Nearly everything else can be considered an object (including arrays).

Variables with a primitive numeric value are merely pointers to the current value. As a result, the following expression will return `true`:

```
1 <= 2
```

But the following expression can *never* be true:

```
date1 <= date2
```

...unless at some point you explicitly set both variables to be pointers to the same object:

```
date1 = date2
```

Because these are objects, `<=` does not compare the *values* they represent. The `=` checks to see if they are pointers to the exact same in-memory *object*. Unless the operands are primitive, the `<` half of the operator is meaningless, because two object variables can never be "less" than each other, they can only either be pointers to the *same* object or pointers to *different* objects; the former would make them "equal", the latter would not, even if the two objects identified by the two variables store an identical internal value. They are separate memory allocations, so JavaScript does not consider them to be equal to each other and cannot compare their values using standard comparison operators.

Comment: Additional bonus answer: to ease simplicity of date comparisons I added isBefore, isAfter, equalsIgnoreTime etc methods to the NotesDateTime class in the OpenNTF Domino API.

Comment: var first = "10/15/2013".split("/")
                               var second = "01/02/2014".split("/")
                               var firstDate=new Date();
                               firstDate.setFullYear(first[2],(first[0] - 1 ),first[1]);

                               var secondDate=new Date();
secondDate.setFullYear(second[2],(second[0] - 1 ),second[1]);

                               if (+firstDate <= +secondDate)
{
return "Pass"
}
else
{
return "Fail"
}